# Counting lines in a file during particular timestamps in bash

Tags: bash, awk, timestamp

I am scheduling a cron that runs every minute and gives the word count of `REJECT` for every minute. My file is logged continuously and to avoid redundant read, I store the lines I read last time while running the script using tail -n +lastTimeWC. But how do I count number of REJECT per minute. sample input:

```
20170327-09:15:01.283619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:15:01.287619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:15:01.289619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:15:01.290619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:15:01.291619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:15:01.295619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:15:01.297619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:16:02.283619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:16:03.283619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:17:02.283619074 ResponseType:REJECT
20170327-09:17:07.283619074 ResponseType:REJECT
```

Expected Output:

```
9:15 REJECT 7
9:16 REJECT 2
9:17 REJECT 2
```

Update1: (Using Ed Morton's answer)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while :
do
awk -F '[:-]' '{curr=$2":"$3} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print NR, prev, $NF, cnt; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr}' $1
sleep 60
done
```

This script continuously gives me output after 60 seconds. But it should only give new timestamps added to the logfile `($!)` Suppose 9:18 gets added, then it should just start including that to the answer (not 9:15 to 9:18 all again)

Comment: Yes, I put a minutely cron, but that cannot be exact,  so I cut uniq hr:min from incremented log and want to subtract 1 min from that time and grep -c . But still its complicated, I seek some idea to approch this problem, not the code

Answer (score 2):

Don't print the last count since it may not be complete for that timestamp, just print the counts before that:

```
$ awk -F '[:-]' '{curr=$2":"$3} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print prev, cnt, $NF; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr}' file
09:15 REJECT 7
09:16 REJECT 2
```

If you really WANTED to print the last one too then just add a print in an END section:

```
$ awk -F '[:-]' '{curr=$2":"$3} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print prev, $NF, cnt; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr} END{print prev, $NF, cnt}' file
09:15 REJECT 7
09:16 REJECT 2
09:17 REJECT 2
```

but I'd imagine you have to just discard that possibly partial result anyway so what's the point?

Note that you don't have to store all the results in an array and then print them in the END section, just print them every time the timestamp changes. In addition to using memory unnecessarily, the solutions that store all of the results in an array and then print them with a loop in the END section using `in` will print the output in random (actually hash) order, not the order the timestamps occur in your input (unless by dumb luck sometimes).

Rather than storing the line count of your input file (which can cause false results when a timestamp results are split across invocations of the script AND makes it impossible to use `logrotate` or similar to truncate your log file as it's getting long/old), store the last timestamp analyzed and start after that on the current iteration, e.g. do the equivalent of this with cron:

```
while :
do
    results=( $(awk -F '[:-]' -v last="$lastTimeStamp" '{curr=$2":"$3} curr<last{next} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print prev, $NF, cnt; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr}' file) )
    numResults="${#results[@]}"
    if (( numResults > 0 ))
    then
        printf '%s\n' "${results[@]}"
        (( lastIndex = numResults - 1 ))
        lastResult="${results[$lastIndex]}"
        lastTimeStamp="${lastResult%% *}"
    fi
    sleep 60
done
```

or if you wanted to use line numbers so you can do `tail` then rather than using `wc -l` to get the length of the file (which would include the current timestamp you are not printing potentially incomplete results for), have awk print the line number of the line after the last line associated with each timestamp:

```
$ awk -F '[:-]' '{curr=$2":"$3} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print NR, prev, $NF, cnt; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr}' file
8 09:15 REJECT 7
10 09:16 REJECT 2
```

and strip it off to save the last value before printing the result. That last value is what you'll do `tail -n +<startLineNr> | awk '...'` with next iteration.

btw you didn't show us this in  your sample input but if your log file contains lines that do not contain REJECT and you want those ignored, just add `$NF!="REJECT"{next}` at the start of the awk script.

Comment: Mortan, thanks for the answer. `do the equivalent of this with cron` did that mean to put a cron script using the while code? I hope my problem is clear (that file is constantly increasing in length) and I need a minutely Reject count log file (even if it lags by 2-3 minutes), this logfile is appended every minute

Comment: line 8: results: bad array subscript when file is not updating with new times

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. No, I don't mean put that in a cron job - there's 2 ways to call a script every minute, one is from a cron job and the other is a loop with sleep 60 as I've shown. I'm just saying do **the equivalent** in a cron job. You did say `I seek some idea to approch this problem, not the code`. Just add a test for the array being non-empty (`(( numResults != 0 ))`) before accessing its elements.

Comment: I'm still learning awk and not clear about how this code works. After every 60 seconds it prints (what it has printed before aswell, it doesnt need to continuously check if status is updated. Once it has printed, it should not re-evaluate). I think you are considering the case where at 9:20, I get a 9:15 `reject` and should update my reject count. But this is not required, because file is logged serially only

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand your comment. Every 60 seconds the script just prints what was logged in the past 60 seconds. wrt `at 9:20, I get a 9:15 reject ....` - all the script does is not print the stats for the very last timestamp in the file since whatever is generating the log file might be in the middle of recording info for that timestamp when this script runs so the script doesn't know if that last record is complete or not. It doesn't try to reanalyze previously reported timestamp records. Just try running it. Add some `print`s to help trace what it's doing if you like.

Comment: Yes, you  have handled the case of last minute time log not completely written very well. Just that since my file will be very large, I dont want to re-read again from start (which happens after every 60 seconds). Is there a way to `ignore` previously read log. That was why I was thinking of using line count that have already been read.

Comment: In my answer I showed you 2 ways to do that - 1) pass the previous last-processed timestamp to awk so it keeps just doing `next` until past that one (see the text starting from `Rather than storing the line count `), or 2) have awk print the line number after the last one processed so you can `tail` from that point on the next iteration (see the text starting from `or if you wanted to use line numbers`). Take your pick. The `tail` one will probably be more efficient.

Comment: If I run the `awk -F '[:-]' '{curr=$2":"$3} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print NR, prev, $NF, cnt; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr}' file` in a while loop, it works perfectly, but prints same result every minute even if file has not changed. How do I make it print (or append )only when it has found something new logged in the file? Looks to be very close but im missing something  here. btw thanks for extended help

Comment: Again, see my answer for the 2 ways I showed you to do that. Not sure where we're disconnecting - it's right there in my answer using either `-v last="$lastTimeStamp"` or `tail -n +...`.

Comment: I added where I am stuck, by updating my question . Thanks

Comment: Change the `while` loop you just added to your question to be the `while` loop in my answer. Again, not sure where we're disconnecting. Is there something about the code of my while loop that's confusing? Do you have any questions about any of the lines in that loop? I tried to use many well named variables to make it clear... I just noticed a typo `numResults="${#result[@]}"` should be `numResults="${#results[@]}"`, I fixed that now and added protection against no results.

Comment: Could you please explain what 1st line of while does? Where does it ensure that it is not doing rework. If not then why does it print the same thing again after 60 secs (it should just do nothing and wait for something new in the logfile). Sorry if I sound too dumb :(

Comment: the first line calls awk and saves its output in a shell array. Saving `lastTimeStamp` from the awk output and then passing it back into awk on next iteration as `last` and then `curr<last{next}` is what ensures it doesn't print the previous results again.

Comment: ` doesn't print the previous results again` but if you run this script on the file it **Does** print same result again and again if file is not updated rather than being just silent. I think here is where we differ, you are assuming it prints only once, but if you try running it by copying content in a file and running the script, you  will notice it prints same result again.

Comment: https://ideone.com/xN4vjG This is what the current script and log looks like. If you run this, it clearly prints output again and again. I tried following the code in debugger aswell (if you uncomment set x trap)

Comment: You can see you're getting an error message, right? In stderr? So debug it! The message says "illegal array subscript". OK what is that subscript value? What should it be instead? Why is it the wrong value? What change do I need in the code to make it the right value? etc. This is nothing to do with awk, it's the shell script calling it. Again, you said you wanted "some idea, not the code" - I gave you the idea and a pretty good start at the code.

Comment: Yes your idea & code both are above expected from the post. Maybe it has to do with my inexperience with awk. I am still trying my best to understand it.`awk -F '[:-]' -v last="$lastTimeStamp"` creates a variable (intially null),`curr=9:12` `curr<last{next}` what is this doing ?  I think you are creating results array having 3 elements, prev,$NF,cnt. Then print the array,count number of elements in array (in numResults) `${lastResult%% *}"` what it does ? Anyway thanks for the help and time

Comment: If curr is 9:12 and last is null - is the condition `curr<last` true or false? How about when curr is 9:13 and last is 9:12? You can look up `next` in the awk man page. See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html for what `%%` does. Again - add some printfs to see what's happening.

Comment: Trying through line number method. `That last value is what you'll do tail -n +<startLineNr> | awk '...' with next iteration.`  In the next iteration, if we use `tail -n +12 | awk .. ` then line number is printed as 2 (if total 14 lines) and next iteration will just start from tail -n +2 again. My try: https://ideone.com/hR6bgt

Comment: Add startLineNr to whatever number of lines awk returns to get the total.to use as the next startLineNr. I didn't look at your try. If you have another question then accept an answer to this question then post a stand-alone followup question on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `Awk`, by hashing the minute value as the index and *assuming the status does not change* per minute, something as below,

```
awk -F'[-:]' '{unique[$2":"$3]++; uniqueValue[$2":"$3]=$NF; next}END{for (i in unique) print i,uniqueValue[i],unique[i]}' file
09:15 REJECT 7
09:16 REJECT 2
09:17 REJECT 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be a nice approach. ` assuming the status does not change per minute`. What does this mean ? Basically this file is continuously being written. So at 9:15 when my cron script gives me say 10 lines of 9:15 time then I cannot be sure if logging for 9:15 is over. So I think we should check for a minute earlier (to be sure that all 9:14 are taken into account) then at 9:16 we check for all 9:15 and so on. (There could be better way to, but that how I think right now)

Comment: @pythonRcpp: I just meant that the status `REJECT` will not change within a minute, e.g. for 30s in `9:15` it is `REJECT` and some other for next 30s

Comment: No, once something is logged, it stays permanently. I hope you are able to understand my problem of (making sure all per minute values to be considered, by running for a minute or two later timestamps)

Comment: @pythonRcpp: Can you actually run this in your log file and report back? to see if it is working. I will remove this, if it does not solve your problem.

Comment: @Inian - Just to add a shorter version of your code - 
`awk -F'[-: ]' '{a[$2":"$3" "$NF]++} END {for(i in a) print i,a[i]}' f`

Comment: You should mention that'll output the results in random order, not the order they occur in the input (unless by luck sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Including the REJECT filter, the date and in stream version (no array in memory, just last counter and date reference

```
awk -F '-|:..[.]|pe:' '$NF=="REJECT"{if(L==$1"-"$2)C++;else{print L" REJECT " C;C=1;L=$1"-"$2}}END{print L" REJECT " C}' YourLog
```

Including the 'not retreat same info' like asked in comment (just see in code the "last know time" that is reread)

```
CFile=Counter.log
# just to insure there is a counter file (could be empty) for awk input
touch ${CFile}
awk -F '-|:..[.]|pe:' -v CF="${CFile}" '
   FNR==NR {
      if( CF == FILENAME) {L=$0;next}
      }

   # dont treat element before 
   # (so we include last know time that was maybe still logging at last cycle)
   L > ( $1 "-" $2 ) { next }

   $NF=="REJECT" {
      if(L==$1"-"$2)C++
       else {
         print L" REJECT " C;C=1;L=$1"-"$2
         }
      }
   END{
      print L" REJECT " C
      # write new counter info
      print L > CF
      }
   ' ${CFile} YourLog
```

Comment: Does it ensure no re-reading of already processed portion of logfile ?

Comment: no, for this you need to add an extra info like a second file with last list reach or time reached. I will add a second snippet for this

Comment: yes that would be very helpful and ensures no re-reading of file. Also we would then just keep appending the output from script and not re-write from start

Comment: the script reread the full log but only extract "new part" except the very last time treated because it could be still in treatment when log was treated on previous cycle. Need a flag in code if you would remove also this.