# Working with continuously appended log file in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a continuously appended logfile like below. My intent is to find REJECT counts every minute. A minutely cron cannot be synchronized in a way thatit runs at exactly 9:15:00 is what creates this problem tricky.

```
20160302-09:15:01.283619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:15:01.287619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:15:01.289619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:15:01.290619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:15:01.291619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:15:01.295619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:15:01.297619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:16:02.283619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:16:03.283619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:17:02.283619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:17:07.283619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:18:07.283619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:19:06.283619074 ResponseType:ACCEPT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:10|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:19:07.283619074 ResponseType:ACCEPT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:10|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:19:07.283619075 ResponseType:ACCEPT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:10|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:20:07.283619075 ResponseType:ACCEPT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:10|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:21:07.283619075 ResponseType:ACCEPT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:10|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
20160302-09:22:07.283619074 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274
```

Expected output

```
8 9:15 REJECT 7
10 9:16 REJECT 2
12 9:17 REJECT 2
#continue appending every 2 minutes or so by reading more logged lines eg. 9:19 then 9:22 and so on
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
touch ${today}.log
counter=$(tail -1 ${today}.log | cut -d" " -f1) #get line number to tail from

re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $counter =~ $re ]] ; then
   counter=1
fi
echo "$counter"

echo "tail -n +$counter $1 | grep "ErrorCode:100107" |cut -d'|' -f1 | awk -F '[:-]' '{curr=$2":"$3} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print NR, prev, $NF, cnt; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr}' >> ${today}.log"
tail -n +$counter $1 | grep "ErrorCode:100107" |cut -d'|' -f1 | awk -F '[:-]' '{curr=$2":"$3} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print NR, prev, $NF, cnt; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr}' >> ${today}.log
```

I intend to run this script every 2 or 3 minutes (delayed logging is okay for now). But dont want to re-read the whole file every time(file will be in GBs), so I tried using line number and tail only added line. But this fails as during the second iteration, line numbers are reset. Is there a way to work only on newly added lines.

Update1:
To generate continuous logfile

```
while :; do echo "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S).21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT|OrderID:4000007|Symbol:-10|Side:S|Price:175|Quantity:10000|AccountID:BMW500  |ErrorCode:100107|TimeStamp:1490586301283617274";sleep $(shuf -i 5-20 -n 1);done >> test_log &
```

I run script with test_log as argument `./myscript.sh test_log`
Content of myscript.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

inputfile=$1

tail -f $inputfile | grep "ErrorCode:100107" |cut -d'|' -f1 | awk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK]+1;delete a};LK=key}' FS='[-:]' #does not give output on teminal
# however this works=> cat $inputfile | grep "ErrorCode:100107" |cut -d'|' -f1 | awk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK]+1;delete a};LK=key}' FS='[-:]'
```

This somehow does not give me continuous output on terminal

Reference:
[Counting lines in a file during particular timestamps in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038565/counting-lines-in-a-file-during-particular-timestamps-in-bash)

Comment: I know a complete different way that is much more simple. But this will work only in combination with `systemd`. Do you use Linux and what service you reading from ?

Comment: Yes I use Linux machine, file is read from a simple logfile being appended by a cpp binary

Comment: Use `sleep` instead of `cron` and keep your script running.

Answer (score 2):

This `gawk` will *update* your *results* on each *timestamp* iteration:

```
tail -f your_log_file|gawk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key}' FS='[-:]'
```

Simple and minimal memory overhead.

---

**Explanation**

`FS='[-:]'`: The `F`ield `S`eparator  is set to `-` and `:` using a `regex`.

`/RMS_REJECT/`: **Only rejected records are taken in consideration**, so  we look for the appropriated pattern, and *do nothing* when not present in the line.

`key=$2":"$3`: Composes a `key` based in second and third field.

`a[key]++`:  Stores the *key* in an *associate array* (kind of hash) and accumulates the number of times that key is seen.

*We're going to skip the if part explanation for a moment.*

`LK=key`: `LK` stands for *Last Key*, so we use this variable to store the *last* key processed.

`if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]}`: When our *Last Key* has a value and its content differs from the current one (`key` var), print the *Last Key* and its hash value and delete de key from the array to avoid memory overhead.

---

**Example**

```
[klashxx]$ while :; do echo "$(date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S).21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT";sleep $(shuf -i 5-20 -n 1);done >> test_log &
[1] 4040
[klashxx]$ tail -f test_log |gawk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key}' FS='[-:]'
09:22 6
09:23 5
09:24 6
09:25 3
^C
```

*(Control + C  pressed)*

---

```
[klashxx]$ cat test_log 
20170405-09:22:13.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:22:20.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:22:29.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:22:44.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:22:53.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:23:07.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:23:22.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:23:38.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:23:45.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:23:55.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:24:05.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:24:16.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:24:24.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:24:31.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:24:43.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:24:56.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:25:13.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:25:23.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:25:43.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
20170405-09:26:01.21223 ResponseType:RMS_REJECT
```

---

**PS**

Don't `grep` and `cut`, just use `gawk` check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360640/tail-f-into-grep-into-cut-not-working-properly).

---

**PS2**

Based on your code, the final thing should look this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

inputfile=$1

tail -f $inputfile | gawk -v errorcode="100107" '/RMS_REJECT/ && $20 == errorcode{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key}' FS='[-:|]'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get `09:16 2
09:17 2
09:18 1` running your command

Comment: Works awesome, but I need to completely understand its working (the `awk` thing) we create a key as HH:MM and then. Could you please elaborate. BTW this is extremely terse and clean. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the explanation,indeed very helpful. why `a[LK]+1` ? also when Im using the same command in a bash script no output comes on screen (I would ideally like to run ./myscript logfile with output on stdout. If instead of tail -f I use cat in the script then it runs fine. Maybe it has to do something with how tail -f works inside bash script.

Comment: tail -f $inputfile | grep "ErrorCode:100107" |cut -d'|' -f1 | awk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK]+1;delete a};LK=key}' FS='[-:]' 
#this works cat $inputfile | grep "ErrorCode:100107" |cut -d'|' -f1 | awk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK]+1;delete a};LK=key}' FS='[-:]'

Comment: Yes, it works if i simply use awk..interesting ! Let me read the link you shared and get back if I still have doubts. Still overwhelmed by this classic approach :) Thanks a ton

Comment: An interesting case came up in this. Suppose it is 9:16 and 100 rejects came, and then none came. The script would keep on waiting for `key` to change before it prints the result. Is there someway to cover that case...something like if current time is more than key then don't wait for new key

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach the problem is to use `stat` to save the log size and `dd` to skip over the old information in the log to handle only the `REJECT` codes received in the last minute. You can time your next loop to start precisely on the next minute by `sleep`ing the number of seconds until the next minute (e.g., `:00` seconds) with `sleep $((60 - $(date +%S)))`.

A short example might be something like the following for any logfile given as the first argument (or `/path/to/logfile` by default). You will need to add your REJECT logic:

```
#!/bin/bash

lfn=${1:-/path/to/logfile}

size=$(stat -c "%s" "$lfn")         ## save original log size

while :; do

    newsize=$(stat -c "%s" "$lfn")  ## get new log size
    if ((newsize > size)); then     ## if change, use new info

        ## use dd to skip over existing text to new text
        newtext=$(dd if="$lfn" bs="$size" skip=1 2>/dev/null)

        ## process newtext however you need
        printf "\n newtext: %s\n" "$newtext"


    elif ((newsize < size)); then   ## handle log truncation

        newtext=$(dd if="lfn" 2>/dev/null)
        if [ -n "$newtext" ]; then

            ## process newtext however you need
            printf "\n newtext: %s\n" "$newtext"

        fi

    fi

    size=$((newsize));              ## update size to newsize

    sleep $((60 - $(date +%S)))     ## sleep seconds until next min

done
```

You could use something like `nrejects=$(grep -c RMS_REJECT <<<"$newtext")` to get the number of rejections on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I present a complete different approach!

I have not `cpp`installed, but `cpp` depends on `libc`, so `journal` should be used anyway.

I found [this example](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/journal-submit.html) on the internet to set up the programming code.

Then I used [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs) to learn `journalctl commands`.

the hole magic...
You need to have a `service` within `systemd` to read from. Most easy way is to call `systemctl list-units` and search for the service you want to read from.

Then you can use `Journalctl -f` (its like `tail -f`) to print out every new entry created. You can also dictate the output. No more need for `awk` or similar, instead you can use JSON or what every you want.

I hope this will help your future projects too!

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way could be to `tail -f` the logfile and redirect it's output to a fifo and have an awk work on the fifo, something like this:

Simulating a logfile:

```
$ while true ; do echo foo ; sleep 1 ; done > simulated_logfile
```

Make a fifo:

```
$ mkfifo fifo
```

`tail -f` the logfile and feed the fifo:

```
$ tail -f simulated_logfile > fifo
```

Process the output with awk continuously:

```
$ awk '{print NR}' fifo
```

Make your awk script to gather info to a hash until the minute changes and then output, reset vars and continue gathering because once the awk script exits, the `tail` process will stop also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below bash+awk to solve your dynamic log reading.

```
$ cat logappend.sh 
#!/bin/bash
start=1
end=$(wc -l < file)
while [ 1 ]
do
awk -v start=$start -v end=$end -F '[|:-]' '/ErrorCode:100107/ && (NR>=start && NR<= end) {curr=$2":"$3} (prev!="") && (curr!=prev){print NR, prev, $5, cnt; cnt=0} {cnt++; prev=curr}' file > output.txt
cat output.txt
sleep 20
start=$end
end=$(wc -l < file)
done
```

> NOTE : You need to change the sleep time as per your need.

For a 1st run, it will run for complete file and from the 2nd run, it will check only for the new lines that have been added to the existing file by changing the start and end variable.

Processing... for 1st run -

```
$ ./logappend.sh 
8 09:15 RMS_REJECT 7
10 09:16 RMS_REJECT 2
11 09:17 RMS_REJECT 1
18 09:15 RMS_REJECT 7
20 09:16 RMS_REJECT 2
script is going to sleep for 20 sec
```

this script will wait for 20 sec and then look for new changes in the file by assigning the previous end value to start variable and set a new value for end variable.
For testing, I have copied only first 10 lines of files to the existing files

```
cp file tempfile
head tempfile >> file
```

### to append the 10 lines to file

In the meanwhile your 20 sec will be completed and you can see the new output -

```
21 09:17 RMS_REJECT 20
28 09:15 RMS_REJECT 7
30 09:16 RMS_REJECT 2
script is going to sleep for 20 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '[.|[:blank:]]+' -v FlushLast=0 '
   # assume first time for counter + init
   BEGIN {
      CounterFile = ARGV[ ARGC - 2]
      printf( "" ) >> CounterFile
      Count = 0
      }

   # Load last know reference
   FILENAME == CounterFile {
      Last = $1
      LastRef = 1
      next
      }

   # skip earlier stat
   $1 <= Last {
      next
      }

   # treat new date change
   Last != $1 {
      if( ! LastRef ) {
         print Last " " Count
         print Last " " Count >> CounterFile
         }
      LastRef = 0
      Last = $1
      Count = 0
      }

   # count reject
   $3 ~ /REJECT/ {
      Count++
      }

   # if you want the very last date also (if FlusLast==2 mean next cycle it s ommited )
   END {
      if( FlushLast ) {
         # printf( "flush: " )
         print Last " " Count
         if ( FlushLast > 1 ) print Last " " Count >> CounterFile
         }
      }
   ' ${today}.Counter ${today}.log
```

Note:

- parameter FlushLast allow to print last 'unfinished' stat (1 print only, 2 print + counter, 0 not stat)
- a counter file is created (assume per *today* name but could be uniq also or anywhere else)