# awk using multiple variable from different regex

Tags: bash, awk

I am stuck in an edge case of the following command for [Working with continuously appended log file in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222728/working-with-continuously-appended-log-file-in-bash) question

```
tail -f your_log_file|gawk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key}' FS='[-:]'
```

The problem arises when I have only 1 instance of key for the whole day and LK != key never happens

```
tail -f your_log_file|gawk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key}' <last key LK to be taken from just tail -1 of your_log_file and not RMS_REJECT filtered> FS='[-:]'
```

Is there a way to set `LK = "$2:$3"` of normal (unfiltered by RMS_REJECT) file. Basically that compares  (last key of RMS_REJECT and last key of current time) and hence solves the problem.

I tried `tail -f $inputfile | awk 'BEGIN {FS='[-:]' ;LK=$2":"$3 }/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK]+1;delete a}}' FS='[-:]'`

My 2nd try

`tail -f $inputfile | awk '/RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;print LK,key ;if (LK && LK != key){print key,a[key]+1;delete a}} /PATTERN2/{LK=$2":"$3; }' FS='[-:]'` assume pattern 2 exists at every line (not containing RMS_REJECT)

Comment: Don't assume people are going to go clicking links to try to piece together your question. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output and add some white space and indenting to your code so it's legible. Otherwise the pool of people willing to invest far more time than necessary into trying to understand your question so they can help you will be relatively small...

Answer (score 0):

Normaly you should *simply* add the case at the end:

```
tail -f your_log_file|gawk '
   /RMS_REJECT/{key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key}
   END {if ( !LK ){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key}
   ' FS='[-:]'
```

but you work on a stream (so no end normaly) -> you need to set another trigger.
Use something like (assuming here that $1 is a date like YYYY/MM/DD)

```
tail -f your_log_file|gawk '
   NR==1 {LD=$1}
   /RMS_REJECT/ {key=$2":"$3;a[key]++;if (LK && LK != key){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key}
   $1 != LD {if ( !LK ){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key;LD=$1}
   ' FS='[-:]'
```

Comment: I think I simply need to put `LK = hh:mm` at the end right ! or is there something I'm missing? I cant really understand what `$1 != LD {if ( !LK ){print LK,a[LK];delete a[LK]};LK=key;LD=$1}` in your case is doing ` could you elaborate

Comment: first remark: there is no sample of your log file so no idea od content and structure, i juste assume date is first maybe also second field like in many log file. $1 != LD is, in this case, a trigger at day change($1 is day by assumption) occuring at first event after a treated day. code is just the same as previous print + a reset of LD (Last Date variable)

Comment: sample logfile is there in the question link. You are correct that every line starts with time and $2":"$3 will make an hh:mm key. I updated my last try which should work but still seems to have some issue. Basically I'm saying key1 is from line containing RMS_REJECT  and LK is from line containing some pattern2 .